# Why does everyone use Git in a centralized manner?

Tags: version-control, git

I have used Git at my past two companies for version control. It seems from what I've heard that about 90% of companies use Git over other version control systems.

One of the biggest selling points of Git is that it is decentralized, i.e. all repositories are equal; there is no central repository/ source of truth. This was a feature [Linus Torvalds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds) championed.

But it seems that every company used Git in a centralized manner, much like one would use SVN or CVS. There is always a central repository on a server (usually on GitHub) that people pull from and push to. I have never seen or heard of (in my admittedly limited experience) people using Git in the truly decentralized manner in which it was intended, i.e. pushing and pulling to other colleagues repositories as they saw fit.

My questions are:

1. Why don't people use a distributed workflow for Git in practice?
2. Is the ability to work in a distributed manner even important to modern version control, or does it just sound nice?

### Edit

I realized I didn't get across the correct tone in my original question. It sounded like I was asking why anyone would work in a centralized manner when a [distributed version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control) (DVCS) was so obviously superior. In actuality, what I meant to say was, *I don't see any benefits to DVCS at all*. Yet I often hear people preaching its superiority, while the real-world seems to agree with my view.

Comment: I feel the exact same way, and do not understand this.

Comment: Personally, I just don't know of any use cases for multiple remotes, other than forks for creating PRs to the main remote. The distributed thing is still useful because it means I get a complete history on my machine without having to talk to the network, and I can do some work offline if I really want to, and it's much easier to migrate from one online repo host to another. What exactly do you have in mind when you refer to a "distributed workflow"?

Comment: I am fairly certain Torvalds intended from the beginning to have one "source of truth" Linux Kernel repository.

Comment: Having a team of 10, it doesn't seem very practical if they all have to pull from each other? Where will the 'final' code be for e.g. a release? What if a collegue has a critical piece but you haven't pulled from him, then he leaves on vacation without internet access? Etc..

Comment: Ultimately, software itself *is* centralized.  Customers don't buy branches or remotes, they buy a final, put-together, built product.  There always needs to be some central path forward.

Comment: Just because your company needs to release exactly one controlled version of its software doesn't mean that its developers can't benefit from working decentralized among themselves while developing that one, central version. Git allows them to do this.

Comment: To me git's "decentralized-ness" is one of the least important features recommending it. The ability to do frequent commits and rollbacks locally, without affecting anyone else, or powerful techniques such as rebasing are where git really shines in my workflow. It's possible (indeed probable) that all these are made possible by being decentralized, but the "D" in DVCS isn't that important by itself to me.

Comment: @Jayraj *"To me git's "decentralized-ness" is one of the least important features recommending it. The ability to do frequent commits and rollbacks locally, without affecting anyone else, or powerful techniques such as rebasing are where git really shines in my workflow."*  Aren't those abilities precisely part of it being decentralized?  You have your own repository, which means that you can have things *locally*, without needing to talk to a central server.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Like I said it's probable that being decentralized allows git to do all these things (I don't know enough about VCS design to know for sure). But one could still build a DVCS that doesn't have local commits or rebasing; the "D" is necessary but not sufficient. EDIT: I guess a DVCS without local commits is kind of stupid and unworkable. But rebase isn't necessarily a given with "distributed-ness".

Comment: You are not _forced_ to work like this by the technology, but you may _choose_ to work like this (as you most likely need a canonical place for the released sources).

Comment: There is a difference between decentralized and distributed.

Comment: Servers are always available. Your co-workers might be sick. It takes extra work to start the git server, and open ports on routers, and ensure authentication. When GitHub was down and my co-worker pushed/pulled changes directly to me, that's when I realized the power of Git. I've never needed it since however.

Comment: Really you should play with a non-distributed VCS like Subversion over an unstable link to a far, far away server. Or even without any connection the server whatsoever. *Then* you will understand.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38377/discussion-on-question-by-gardenhead-why-does-everyone-use-git-in-a-centralized).

Comment: Your premise is flawed: In practice, each maintainer has their own tree and they use git in a decentralized manner.

Comment: I like this question. On our teams people won't even use each other's feature branches, everyone wants a merge to develop before they work on their own part.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Ahh, but in fact you *are* using git in a decentralized manner!

Let us compare git's predecessor in mindshare, svn. Subversion had only one "repo", one source of truth. When you did a commit, it was to a single, central repo, to which every other developer was committing as well.

This sort of worked, but it led to numerous problems, the biggest one being the dreaded *merge conflict*. These turned out to be anywhere from annoying to nightmarish to resolve. And with one source of truth, they had a nasty habit of bringing everyone's work to a screeching halt until they were resolved. Merge conflicts certainly exist with git, but they are not work-stopping events and are much easier and faster to resolve; they generally affect only the developers involved with the conflicting changes, rather than everyone.

Then there is the whole single-point-of-failure, and the attendant problems that brings. If your central svn repo dies somehow, you're all screwed until it can be restored from backup, and if there were no backups, you're all doubly screwed. But if the "central" git repo dies, you can restore from backup, or even from one of the other copies of the repo which are on the CI server, developers' workstations, etc. You can do this precisely because they are distributed, and each developer has a first-class copy of the repo.

On the other hand, since your git repo *is* a first-class repo in its own right, when you commit, your commits go to your local repo. If you want to share them with others, or to the central source of truth, you must explicitly do this with a push to a remote. Other developers can then pull down those changes when it's convenient for them, rather than having to check svn constantly to see if someone's done something that will screw them up.

The fact that, instead of pushing *directly* to other developers, you push changes to them indirectly via another remote repo, doesn't matter much. The important part from our perspective is that your local copy of the repo is a repo in its own right. In svn, the central source of truth is enforced by the design of the system. In git, the system doesn't even have this concept; if there is a source of truth, it is decided externally.

Comment: SVN merges also only affect the developers involved with conflicting changes.  One commit makes it into the repo, no conflicting merge can go into the repo until the conflicts are resolved (you can also commit in parallel to a separate branch/path, but that doesn't actually conflict now does it?)

Comment: I find the main difference, when a central server exists, to be that GIT allows ongoing local versioning while the network is down, and SVN doesn't (some other version control systems are even worse, and stop all work when the network is unreachable, because they don't let you change a file until you check it out).

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm pretty sure I didn't make myself clear enough. I'm referring to merging branches, which [svn seems to have a lot of trouble with](https://arialdomartini.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/help-me-because-i-think-martin-fowler-has-a-merge-paranoia/).

Comment: Well, that still doesn't affect everyone, because conflict resolution is done in the working copy of the one person responsible for the merge.  That's true of both SVN and GIT.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh, it's work stopping all right. Remember you have to `svn up` be up to date with the repo before you can check in. When others continue checking in while you're trying to resolve merge conflicts, and give you _another_ set of merge conflicts... you either put a stop to that or you lose what's left of your sanity.

Comment: No, people can definitely keep committing into the branch you're merging changes from, without interrupting your workflow.

Comment: I tend to agree with @BenVoigt that the main difference, in practice, is that git and similar tools are much better at dealing with intermittent or nonexistent network connectivity.  With tools that rely on a central repo, losing access to that repo is at best a moderate setback and at worst a complete blocker.  Git sidesteps that issue (almost) entirely.  Although I think the point about merge conflicts is overstated.  If those happen frequently, the problem is in your task allocation.  You don't want two people changing the same file at the same time, regardless of what VCS tool you use.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, they can, but not into the branch you're merging into. When you develop on trunk, and merge a feature branch into trunk, the problem Michael describes can occur.

Comment: @aroth It's also noticeable when you take a company laptop with you on a business trip, or to work from home. With a centralised VCS, you'd have to set up a VPN just to get at the source. With Git, you just keep working as normal, and push when you get back to the office.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it does the best job of answering my original question, although every answer gave good advice and perspective on the topic. I think the fact that everyone has their own complete and independent repo, even if that repo is not the source of truth, makes the best argument for why decentralized version control is much easier to work with.

Comment: @Luaan: Sounds like you aren't applying the feature branch strategy correctly.  The merging process is supposed to go as follows: (1) Commit all local work into the feature branch.  (2) Merge all trunk commits between the last sync point and trunk HEAD into the feature branch (this does not block trunk) (3) commit to feature branch (4) if trunk has advanced during 2, repeat 2-3 (5) conflict-free merge from feature branch into trunk.  Using this pattern, your local changes are never blocked from being merged, and conflicts occur only to the developer who owns one of the involved branches.

Comment: Ben's right. An SVN repo managed _properly_, and used by a team that has been properly educated in how to develop software, should effectively never have merge conflicts on trunk. You'll only get them when someone's done something wrong and needs to be fired (:P). inb4 it's easier when you don't have to educate people how to use their tools. Yeah, well, there's a lot more to teach about Git than there is about SVN!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38290/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-hampton-why-does-everyone-use-git-in-a-centraliz).

Comment: Since several people ignored my comment about taking the conversation to chat, I'm afraid I'll have to lock the answer.

Comment: Downvoted. This answer is misleading in suggesting foremost that git, by design, offers an advantage when it comes to avoiding merge conflicts.

Answer (score 118):

When your build server (you *are* using CI, right?) creates a build, where does it pull from? Sure, an integration build you could argue does not need "one true repo" but surely a distribution build (i.e. what you give to the customer) does.

In other words: fragmentation. If you designate one repo as "the" repo and appoint guardians who vet pull requests, you have an easy way to satisfy the request of "give me a software build" or "I am new to the team, where is the code?"

The strength of DVCS is not so much the peer-to-peer aspect of it, but the fact that it is *hierarchical*. I modify my workspace, then I commit to local. Once I have a feature complete, I merge my commits and push them to my remote. Then anyone can see my tentative code, provide feedback, etc. before I create a pull request and a project admin merges it into the One True repo.

With traditional CVCS you either commit or you don't. That is fine for some workflows (I use both VCS types for different projects), but falls flat on its face for a public or OSS project. The key is DVCS has multiple steps, which are more work, but provide a better way to integrate code from strangers through a built-in process that allows better visibility into what is being checked in. Using it in a centralized manner means you can still have that gold standard of the current state of the project while also providing a better code sharing mechanism.

Comment: Overall good answer, but I'm pretty sure that Git was in widespread use before Continuous Integration was; our team does use CI, by the way, thanks for checking :D.

Comment: @gardenhead: you missed the point: the same argument holds if one does the integration builds manually. "CI" is just an automatization for a process which is much older that Git.

Comment: "anyone can see my tentative code" -- and they can also pull your tentative code, merge it with their tentative code, and run the tests. This is a pain in centralized VCSes, since it requires branches and changes in the One True Copy. Distributed, you just configure extra remotes, then start merging, patching, and cherry-picking. You have tracking of what you've done but nobody else ever has to see what shenanigans you're up to unless you choose to publish them. In general I recommend nobody should declare DVCS pointless until they've actually used SVN for a large project...

Comment: Interesting logic. Why did Linus decide to design it this way, then? Did he not realize that the build system would impose a central repo anyway? Did he not care?

Comment: Because there is no "one true build" of the linux kernel.  Since everyone builds it themselves, Linus' repo is no more canonical than anyone else's.  If you're selling a product that doesn't work so well.

Comment: @Superbest: a lot (if not all) of the design of git was based around Bitkeeper. Git was created after the linux-bitkeeper controversy imploded.

Comment: @SteveJessop TFS has Shelvesets, which support the "Store tentative, make code review, merge changes" very well.

Comment: @ChristianSauer Yes, but shelveshets are really just lightweight branches (personalized or not). That said, TFS is a whole collaboration system and TFVC (the version control system) is just a small part, and it does work rather well for what it's intended for. But no matter how good TFS is, I love the ability to commit changes locally - and that's already using the D in DVCS :) The same goes for local branches, naturally. And I've used this on TFS and SVN too - just make a local Git repo, no need to push your whole organization to Git :)

Comment: @SteveJessop ... and expanding on that, you can have a feature group set up a Git server (on one of their laptops), and push and pull from that until the feature is done, and then push that back to the central server when that is done. I'm not sure why you'd use a separate server instead of a branch on the main server, but you *can*.

Comment: @gardenhead: _but I'm pretty sure that Git was in widespread use before Continuous Integration was_ Citation needed. As anecdotal evidence, at a previous job, we used Mozilla Tinderbox before git even existed.

Comment: CI was definitely in use (in big shops) long before git. The build cluster (and yes, it was a cluster) at MontaVista was a thing of beauty.

Comment: @ninjalj: presumably, what gardenhead meant is that git was widespread before ci become widespread.

Comment: "With traditional CVCS you either commit or you don't." - that's not true, of course. The normal way of working, on a personal branch, allows you to do whatever you like until your code is merged into the main branch. And the same way of working can in principle be used for "public or OSS project" with an CVCS, although I agree that would be more cumbersome.

Comment: @fishinear in other words with traditional CVCS you commit either to a branch or to trunk _on the server_.

Answer (score 42):

I don't know how you define "everyone", but my team has "a central repo on a server" and *also* from time to time we pull from other colleagues' repos without going via that central repo. When we do this we do still go via a server, because we choose not to email patches about the place, but not via the central repo. This generally happens when a group is collaborating on a particular feature and wants to keep up to date with each other, but as yet has no interest in publishing the feature to everyone. Naturally since we aren't secretive silo-workers those situations don't last long, but DVCS provides the flexibility to do whatever is most convenient. We can publish a feature branch or not according to taste.

But 90%+ of the time, sure, we go via the central repo. When I don't care about any particular change or particular colleague's work it's more convenient, and it scales better, to pull "all my colleagues' changes that have been vetted in the central repo", rather than separately pulling changes from each of N colleagues. DVCS isn't trying to prevent "pull from main repo" being the most common workflow, it's trying to prevent it being the only available workflow.

"Distributed" means that all repos are technically equivalent as far as the `git` software is concerned, but it doesn't follow that they all have equal significance as far as developers and our workflows are concerned. When we release to clients or to production servers, the repo we use to do that has a different significance from a repo used only by one developer on their laptop.

If "truly decentralized" means "there are no special repos" then I don't think that's what Linus means to champion, given that in point of fact he *does* maintain special repos that *are* more important in the grand scheme of things, than is some random clone of Linux that I made yesterday and plan to use only to develop some little patch and then delete it once he's accepted the patch. `git` doesn't privilege his repo over mine, but Linus *does* privilege it. His "is the current state of Linux", mine isn't. So naturally changes *tend* to go through Linus. The strength of DVCS over centralized VCS isn't that there must not be a de facto centre, it's that changes don't have to go through any centre because (conflicts permitting) anyone can merge anything.

DVCS systems are also *forced*, because they are decentralized, to provide certain convenient features based around the fact that you necessarily must have a complete history (i.e. a repo) locally in order to do anything. But if you think about it there's no fundamental reason why you couldn't configure a centralized VCS with a local cache that keeps the whole history for read-only operations permitted to be out of date (I think Perforce has an option for this mode, but I've never used Perforce). Or in principle you could configure `git` with your `.git/` directory on a remote-mounted filesystem in order to emulate the "feature" of SVN that it doesn't work when you don't have a network connection. In effect, DVCS forces the plumbing to be more robust than you can get away with in a centralized VCS. This is a (very welcome) side effect and helped motivate DVCS design, but this distribution of responsibility at the *technical* level isn't the same as fully decentralizing all *human* responsibility.

Comment: They're *technically* equivalent, not *socially* equivalent.

Comment: Emailing patches is fairly painless, just in case anyone is considering it, just use [git format-patch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) and then [git send-email](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email). Did that when I didn't want to fiddle around with Github's access controls and it was very straightforward, everyone has email after all.

Comment: "necessarily must have a complete history [...] locally in order to do anything" -- not true; modern DSCMs support partial repos ("shallow checkouts" in bzr terms, "shallow clones" in git terms).

Answer (score 27):

The interesting thing about the nature of DVCS, is if other people are using it in a distributed manner, you likely wouldn't know it unless they are interacting directly with you.  The only thing you can say definitively is that *you* and your direct teammates don't use git this way.  This doesn't require a company-wide policy.  So I will ask you, why don't *you* use git in a decentralized manner?

To address your edit, perhaps you need some experience working with an actual centralized version control to appreciate the differences, because although they may seem subtle, they are pervasive.  These are all things my team actually does at work that we couldn't do when when we had centralized VCS:

- Have a very small list of core developers with commit access to the "central" repo for each microservice.  Everyone else can work out of forks and submit via pull requests.
- Can commit *much* more frequently, usually several times per hour versus once or twice per day.
- Can create branches for any reason to coordinate temporarily with coworkers, and push to it and pull from it several times per day, then squash it when ready to share with a larger group.  Do you have any idea how hard it is to get permission to create a temporary branch for something like this in a traditional CVCS?

At the risk of sounding old for saying it, you really don't know how easy you have it.

Comment: The question how hard it is to create a branch in a traditional CVCS is entirely down to policy: I happen to work with an upstream SVN repo (naturally via a git-svn clone!), and I have every right to create any branches I want to, even though it's quite a large project. I'm just not allowed to touch a number of designated integration branches, let alone the trunk, without talking to my superiors first. Other companies may have other policies which may be more restrictive, but they certainly don't have to be.

Comment: You're right, I don't know how easy I have it. I wish I had been around in the days of SVN dominance to appreciate how far we've come. As a very young software developer, I find this same pattern repeating quite often: the more experienced devs telling me that the old way of doing something was bad, and this new way / technology is much easier. But I just have to take their word for it; I can never truly appreciate the advantages. I've always found this dissonance difficult to overcome.

Comment: @gardenhead you can always create your own SVN repo and try to break it ;) (and notice how much harder it is than creating a git repo and cloning it...) - One other major feature I've noticed (at least in corporate environments especially) is that file sharing is either a bit awkward, or it's done in such a way that horks up repositories (because virus scanner locks on a network drive, for instance).

Comment: @gardenhead: well, consider yourself lucky that you're not stuck in a legacy project, with old software developers who are telling you _the old way of doing things is just fine_... sometimes you can't help but feel they are just glad they don't need to learn any new technologies!

Comment: @leftaroundabout Sometimes I'm jealous of them, if that is the case. I think since my year working out of college, I've had to learn about one new technology per week.

Comment: @WayneWerner IIRC, sometime after Git became dominant, SVN got "svn init", and the ability to use any old shared directory as a server.

Comment: @gardenhead apparently projects are being released at a pretty insane rate. The ability to continue learning is necessary if you want to be able to find an awesome job.

Comment: and don't forget about walking to school in the rain and snow, almost eight miles uphill both ways.

Comment: @JerryOL: "uphill both ways" yeah, that's what you needed to do to get to that ivory tower.

Comment: All disadvantages you mention are due to very strange company policies, and not inherent limitations of a CVCS. Typically you can limit which users can merge into certain branches, every developer typically works on a personal branch, where you can commit as much as you like, and anybody can typically create new branches (for example if you run two development tasks in parallel).

Comment: Those company policies seem strange now that DVCS is ubiquitous and people are used to its perks.  Before the DVCS revolution, these policies were nearly universal, and they are still very common in large organizations.

Answer (score 20):

I think you're question comes from an (understandable) *always connected* mindset.  *i.e.* The central 'truth' ci server is **always** (or near always) available.  While this is true in most environments, I have worked in at least one which was far from this.

A Military Simulation project my team worked on several years ago.  **All** the code (We're talking a >US$1b codebase) *had to* (by law/international agreement, men in dark suits come if you don't) be on machines **physically isolated from *any* Internet connection**.  This meant the usual situation of we each had 2 PCs, one for writing/running/testing the code, the other to Google things, check E-mail and such.  And there was a *local* network within the team of these machines, obviously not in any way connected to the Internet.

The "central source of truth" was a machine on an army base, in an all-cinderblock underground windowless room (reinforced building, yada-yada).  That machine **also** had no Internet connection.

Periodically, it would be someone's job to transport (physically) a drive with the git repo (containing all our code changes) to the army base - which was several hundred kilometers away, so, you can imagine.

---

Moreover, in *very* large systems where you have **lots** of teams.  They will generally each have their own "central" repo, which then goes back to the actual (god tier) "central" central repo.  I know of at least 1 other contractor who did the same hard-drive git repo dash with their code too.

Also, if you consider something on the scale of the Linux kernel... Developers don't just send a pull request to Linus himself.  It's essentially a hierarchy of repo's - each of which was/is "central" to someone/some team.

The disconnected nature of git means that it can be used in environments where **connected** model source-control tools (*i.e.* SVN, for one) couldn't be used - or couldn't be used as easily.

Comment: I'm a member of the Mile High (Software) Club - I've committed code at 35,000 feet. Sure, planes have Wifi *now*, but that wasn't always the case. And it's nice to know that at least if we crash there's a *possibility* that my team will get my code intact.

Comment: @WayneWerner that's true.  I had been thinking about providing some more generic situations where it wasn't possible to be (near-)always connected.  E.g. on a plane, boat out at sea, space station, remote places in Africa, etc.

Answer (score 19):

Ultimately, you are building a product. This product represents your code at a single point in time. Given that, your code must coalesce *somewhere*. The natural point is a ci server or central server from which the product is built, and it makes sense that this central point is a git repository.

Answer (score 14):

The distributed aspect of a DVCS shows up in open source development all the time, in the form of forking.  For example, some of the projects I contribute to were abandoned by the original author and now have a bunch of forks where the maintainers sometimes pull specific features from one another. Even in general, OSS projects take outside contributions via pull request, rather than by granting random people push access to the ground-truth repo.

This isn't a very common use case when building a concrete product with a specific official release, but in the F/OSS world it's the norm, not the exception.

Comment: That is the right answer, also from a historical point of view. The Linux kernel has had multiple source repositories for a long time (called "trees" by the developers, such as "Linus' tree" or "Andrew's tree"). Linux wanted something to support that type of distributed development when he developed git.

Comment: @Luaan After thinking about this for a while, I realized you're right. I've changed the wording a bit - does this capture the distinction a bit better?

Comment: @fluffy Sounds good to me ;)

Answer (score 9):

> Why does everyone use git in a centralized manner?

We've never met, how comes that you say everyone? ;)

Secondly, there are more other features that you find in Git but not in CVS or SVN. Maybe it's just you assuming that this must be the *only feature* for *everyone*.

Sure many people may use it centralized like CVS or SVN. But don't forget the other feature that inherently comes with a ditributed VCS: all copies are more or less "complete" (all branches and the full history is available) and all branches can be checked out without connecting to a server.

I my opinion this is another feature that should not be forgotten.

While you're not able to do this with out of box CVS and SVN, Git can be used centralized like the former ones without any problems.

So I'm able to commit my changes, maybe squash work-in-progress commits together, then fetch and rebase my work onto the main development branch.

Other features that come out of box with Git:

- cryptographically sign commits
- rebasing (reorder and squash commits; edit commits, not only the message)
- cherry picking
- bisecting the history
- local branches and stashing changes (called "shelving" in Wikipedia)

Also see these three tables in [Wikipedia - Comparison of version control software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version_control_software):

- [Features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version_control_software#Features)
- [Basic commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version_control_software#Basic_commands)
- [Advanced commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version_control_software#Advanced_commands)

So again, maybe the decentralized manner isn't *that only* feature that make people use it.

> 1. Why don't people use a distributed workflow for Git in practice?

Anyone contributing to or hosting a bigger project on Bitbucked, GitHub etc. will excactly do that. The maintainers keep the "main" repository, a contributor clones, commits and then sends a pull request.

In companies, even with small projects or teams, a distributed workflow is an option when they either outsource modules and don't want externals to modify the sacred development branch(es) without having their changes reviewed before.

> 2. Is the ability work in a distributed manner even important to modern version control, ...

As always: it depends on the requirements.

Use a decentralized VCS if any point applies:

- want to commit or navigate the history offline (i.e. finishing the submodule in the mountain cabin during vacation)
- provide central repos but want to keep "the true" repository apart to review changes (i.e. for big projects or distributed teams)
- want to provide (a copy of) the whole history and branches occasionally while preventing direct access to the central repo (similar to the second one)
- want to version something without having to store that remotely or setting up a dedicated repository (especially with Git a mere `git init .` whould be enough to be ready to version something)

There are some more but four should be enough.

> ... or does it just sound nice?

Of course it sounds nice - for beginners.

Comment: Didn't SVN gain `svn init` at some point?

Answer (score 4):

Flexibility is a curse as well as a blessing. And as Git is extremely flexible, it's almost always *far* too flexible for the typical situation. Specifically, most Git projects aren't Linux.

As a result, the smart choice is to remove some of that theoretical flexibility when implementing Git. In theory repositories can form any graph, in practice the usual choice is a tree. We can see the clear benefits using graph theory: in a tree of repositories, any two repositories share exactly one ancestor. In a random graph, the idea of an ancestor doesn't even exist!

Your git client however almost certainly defaults to the "single ancestor" model. And graphs in which nodes have a single ancestor (except for a root node) are exactly trees. So your git client itself defaults to the tree model, and therefore centralized repositories.

Comment: I agree that the flexibility of Git needs to be toned down for most use cases. At my last job, we didn't have guidelines on how to use git, and there were constant conflicts and breakage due to this. At my new company, we use the Git Flow model, and it makes development much more streamlined and stress-free.

Comment: It's not "theoretical flexibility" to allow non-trees.  Restrict yourself to "trees only" and you will never be able to merge in your changes, thus rendering your entire VCS somewhat pointless.

Comment: @Wildcard: Merging is no problem at all with trees, why would that be the case? You can't merge between random nodes, of course, just between parent/child.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, evidently.  I was referring to a tree of commits, not a filesystem tree.  By definition, a merge commit has more than one parent, and your history graph is therefore no longer a tree, but instead is a DAG.

Comment: @Wildcard: MSalters said that *repositories* are usually connected as trees, not that commits are. He's saying that repos usually have only one "upstream" remote that they push to (or issue pull requests to).  I don't have any statistics on whether that's true or not, but it's a completely separate claim from anything to do with how many parents a merge commit has.

Comment: @SteveJessop, thanks for clarifying; that makes much more sense.  I don't know that that's true, but you're right about it being a completely separate claim from what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4):

Business logic rewards a centralized server.  For nearly all realistic business scenarios, a centralized server is a fundamental feature of the workflow.

Just because you have the capacity to do DVCS doesn't mean your primary work flow has to be DVCS.  When I use git at work, we use it in a centralized manner, except for those strange odd cases where the distributed bit was essential to keeping things moving along.

The distributed side of things is complicated.  Typically you want to keep things smooth and easy.  However, by using git you ensure that you have access to the distributed side to deal with the gnarly situations that may arise down the road.

Answer (score 3):

For a coworker to pull from a git repo on my machine means I need to have a git daemon running at root level as a background task. I am very leery of daemons running on my own computer, or on my company-provided laptop. The easiest solution is "NO"! For a coworker to pull from a git repo on my machine also means my internet address needs to be fixed. I travel, I work from home, and I occasionally work from my office.

On the other hand, VPNing to the corporate site and pushing an branch to the central repo takes less than a minute. I don't even need to VPN in if I'm in the office.  My coworkers can easily pull from that branch.

On the third hand, my local git repo is a full-featured repository. I can commit new work, create a new branch for experimental work, and revert work when I make a mess of things, even when I'm working in an airplane flying at 30,000 feet over the middle of nowhere. Try doing that with a centralized version control system.

Comment: " I am very leery of daemons running on my own computer, or on my company-provided laptop." -- because aside from anything else, running a service on my laptop means that the service is unavailable when I close the lid! DynDNS might help with multiple locations (to an extent, you can still be trapped behind a NAT), but it doesn't help with powering down your network card...

Comment: There are plenty of ways of making a git repo visible without running any special daemon; it can be accessed via pretty much any file share (smb, sshfs, etc.), and can even be made available as a plain ol' HTTP store as well.

Answer (score 1):

Complexity:

With a central repository, a typical work flow might be

```
branch off from the central master branch
change the code
test
possibly go back to changing the code
commit
merge any new changes from the central master branch
test
possibly go back to changing the code
merge changes into the central master branch and push
```

The complexity with respect to the number of developers in O(1).

If instead each developer has their own master branch it becomes, for developer 0:

```
branch off from master branch 0
merge from master branch 1
...
merge from master branch N-1
change the code
test
possibly go back to changing the code
commit
merge any changes from master branch 0
merge any changes from master branch 1
...
merge any changes from master branch N-1
test
possibly go back to changing the code
merge changes into master branch 0
```

The peer-to-peer approach is O(N).

Consistency:

Now consider if there is a merge conflict between Alice's master branch and Bob's master branch. Each of the N developers could resolve the conflict differently. Result: chaos.  There are ways of achieving eventual consistency, but until that happens, all sorts of developer time can be wasted.

Comment: If you are going to down vote, could you please leave a comment on why?

Comment: Not that I mind the downvotes.  I just want to know if the answer is wrong in some way.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The distributed features of Git are just extra
complexity that you will never need.

However, in order to understand where this misguided kind of software
came from you first have to understand how people used to work.

As you know, nowadays everyone works on the same machine; we edit files,
compile code, and commit on the same *box*. There is no “my” file or
“your” file or “the server’s” file. It’s just “the file”.

But—if you can imagine for a second—people used to work on their own
machines. No, not like the dumb terminal you use to connect to HQ in
Uzbekistan (from France); they had their own full-fledged “servers” if
you will (I forgot what they used to call it) with their own filesystems
and even own binaries (programs).

Now, they had the *option* of using centralized version control systems
as well back then—they weren’t total brutes—, but they did have some
attempted excuses up their sleeves for using these *D*VCSs:

- You can look at the history locally instead of round-tripping to the
  central repository
- You can experiment “privately” (people used to exploit the fact that
  they had their own machines in order to hide some of what they were
  doing from other people)
- You have the freedom to take a risk on some path of development which
  might be a dead end without impacting anyone else
- Fast merges (?)
- No need for centralized locks on files

Well anyway, not to worry, this is just something of historical
interest; since we only use one single machine per repository, all of
this does not apply anymore.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that many (if not most) teams use Git in a way that resembles centralized version control systems, there are some key aspects of Git's distributed nature that can be beneficial even in these workflows.

1. **Local Operations:** With Git, nearly all operations are local, which makes them fast. You have a complete copy of the project history on your local machine, meaning you don't have to communicate with a server to view commit history, create branches, or switch between branches. This not only improves speed, but also makes it possible to work offline.
2. **Flexible Workflows:** Git's distributed nature makes it flexible in terms of workflows. Teams can structure their use of branches, merges, and forks in a variety of ways to suit their specific processes, team sizes, and project complexities.
3. **Redundancy and Data Integrity:** Every clone of a Git repository is a full backup of the project and its history. This redundancy is an inherent feature of a distributed system and increases data integrity.
4. **Forking:** The ability to fork a project (which is often used in conjunction with a centralized repository, like GitHub) is a direct result of Git's distributed nature. This is particularly useful in open source projects where anybody can fork the main repository, work on their own changes and then propose these changes back to the main project via a pull request.
5. **Isolated Development:** The distributed nature of Git allows developers to experiment with their own versions of the project without interfering with others' work. They can commit changes, and even make mistakes, in their local repository without these impacting the central repository.

So even when used in a centralized way, the underlying distributed nature of Git can still provide advantages. It might be that for many teams the benefits of a centralized model (like easy coordination and clearer access control) are more immediately apparent, while the benefits of a distributed model are subtler or more situational.

Lastly, there's also the issue of industry inertia. Git has become the de facto standard for version control and has a wealth of tooling and resources built around it. So, even if a team doesn't need the distributed aspects of Git, they might use it simply because it's what everyone else uses and it's well supported.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

### Companies are centralized organizations, with centralized workflow.

Every programmer has a boss and he has his boss, etc up to CTO. CTO is the ultimate source of technical truth. Whatever tool company uses, it must reflect this chain of command. A company is like an army - you can't let privates outvote a general.

GIT offers features that are useful to the companies (eg. pull requests for code review) and that alone makes them switch to GIT. The decentralized part is simply a feature they don't need - so they ignore it.

To answer your question:
The distributed part is indeed superior in distributed environment, eg open-source. Results vary depending on who's talking. Linus Torvalds is not exactly your cubicle rat, that's why different features of GIT are important to him than to your github-centric company.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it is because he payroll processing is centralized, so we have to keep a central person happy if we wish to get paid.

Maybe it is because we are creating one product, so we need a master copy of the software for the customers.

Maybe it is because it is a lot easier for a programmer to go to one place to get everyone’s changes, rather than having to connect to lots of different machines.

Maybe it is because the bug database is centralized, **and must be kept in sync with the code**.

***Being centralized is great, until there is a problem…..***

Git being a distributed system allows a new centre to be created at low cost from any up-to-date repository (just expose the repository to the network).   Git also allows an out of date backup to be updated from the repositories on developer machines, so making it easier to recover the centre.

Being able to do merge etc on a local copy of a repository when the network is down is great, but does not need a distributed system; it just needs a system that keeps a local copy of all the data.    Likewise with checking in code with flying etc.

At the end of the day there is little cost for being distributed and some benefits.    Most of the cost of being distributed is in area that are needed if you want great tracking of branches etc.   If you were to design a system for usage in most companies you would not design it to be distributed, as centralized control of the source code is clearly the primary “use case”.